# AWS IAM - Allow user create roles only for services assume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm working on an application and I'm struggling about an issue. My application has Lambdas and DynamoDBs services in which the former needs permissions to call the latter. I solve this creating a role with `Principal` equals `Service: lambda.amazonaws.com`.

I'd like to give access to other developers to create roles too in a way which allows developers to create only roles whose principal is a service or federated and deny if it is user or account.

For example, this role would be allowed:

```
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Federated: cognito-identity.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
      Path: ...
      Policies: ...
```

and this would not be allowed:

```
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              AWS: arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:user/<username>
      Path: ...
      Policies: ...
```

I'm trying to reach this because a user could create a role with admin access and assume it.

Also, is there another way to achieve to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you made any progress on it? I have the same problem while managing my users. I ended up giving them iam:CreateRole among others  in dev along with PowerUserAccess

Comment: @sriharsha186 I didn't find the solution I wanted and I've ended up using a workaround as you did. Check the answer I've just added.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution for my issue and a workaround was creating services roles with a specific path (`/custom-iam/service-role/` for instance) and allow developers to pass only roles with such path:

```
Effect: Allow
Action: iam:PassRole
Resource: 'arn:aws:iam::*:role/custom-iam/service-role/*'
```

Comment: I assume that these service roles are created by Admin user then or through a Pipeline which was created by Admin user. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, only admins can create roles