# IAM policy allow creation of policies, but disallow changes of own account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

For every project, we create two AWS accounts. One for development and staging and one for production. The developers have an IAM user in the root account and users assumed roles in the other accounts to access those.

I want to create a policy, which allows the developer to do nearly everything in the development account, including creating new policies and attaching those (for new resources, etc.), but the developer should not be able to modify his own role / attach new roles to himself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue I've already posted a question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204535/aws-iam-allow-user-create-roles-only-for-services-assume) (similar issue).

After a lot of research, I came to a conclusion: **do not allow developers to create roles and policies.**

**Why?**

1. I didn't find a way to answer my question allowing user creating roles only for resources and not for principals.
2. Even if I've found a solution for 1., there is a flaw: suppose developers can create roles for resources but not for principals and he (she) can create every policy he (she) wants. In this scenario, he (she) could create a policy for Lambdas and inside Lambdas, a script could be written to execute actions allowed by policies attached.

**My final solution:**

Create two groups called **Developers** and **IAM** in which **IAM** users can create any roles and policies, thus is trusted developers, and **Developers** can only attach policies whose path is `services-roles`, for instance.

Example a role attached to **Developers** group - allow users create everything except all `iam` actions except `PassRole` with path `service-roles`:

```
DevelopersIAMManagedPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Description: 'Developers.'
      # Groups:
      #   - String
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: iam:PassRole
            Resource: 'arn:aws:iam::*:role/projects-roles/*'
          - Effect: Allow
            NotAction: iam:*
            Resource: '*'
```

I'm open to new ideas, but this solution is the most secure I've reached.

Comment: Thanks for sharing our research results! Looks like a practical option, but not perfect... Maybe the bettwer way is to disallow all write actions inside both accounts and let only the codepipline do everything? But saddly there are still some problems which cannot be solved with cloudformation...

Comment: This is a sensible approach. If somebody has the ability to create IAM users/roles, then they can probably get access to use them. That's why it is sensible to separate Dev/Test from Production accounts.

Comment: @SnowMax yes, it's not perfect. Let's discuss how to achieve a better approach.  "some problems which cannot be solved with cloudformation" which problems are you talking about?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, it's a sensible approach. Because of that, I wrote "thus is trusted developers" only trusted people can get IAM policies.

Comment: @PedroArantes One problem we have for exmaple is that cloudformation still doesn´t support the preTokenTrigger for Cognito. So After creating a new Stack the devloper has to run a script to fix that.